# export kindle purchase history report?

Tags: amazon, export, kindle

How do I get a report of Kindle purchases?  The context is that I've "purchased" a number of free books from Amazon for an Amazon Kindle e-reader.  Scrolling through most show zero dollar cost.

I just want to see a spreadsheet to confirm nothing expensive was purchased accidentally.

Optimally, a spreadsheet showing each and every purchase amount and date for Amazon.  However, Kindle specific would be more than sufficient.  Perhaps even export the data to google sheets..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the report:
https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200131240

Direct to the report generating tool, enter dates, wait, download: https://www.amazon.com/gp/b2b/reports

Getting the results into a google sheet:
Go into google drive and hit new and select upload, when you open a csv in drive there is abutton to open it with google sheets that will convert it.

This link has a explanation with some other tips.
https://www.geek.com/apps/geek-101-how-to-open-a-csv-document-with-google-docs-1551489/

Comment: Doesn't work for kindle content orders. Just the physical items they have shipped.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, we built a little tool to help people parse that Amazon CSV export: [nozama.dev](https://nozama.dev)

... it lets you sort and filter by category / spending / year / etc...

Nozama is free / opensource. It's more of a project to scratch a personal itch than anything, but I'd love to hear people's suggestions as to how we can make it better.